# How to use apply() combined with match() in R?

Tags: r, match, apply

I am trying to replace values in data frame with values from a table.

```
df <- read.table(text=" v1  v3_1    v3_3    v3_4    v3_5    v4_1    v4_3    v4_4    v4_5    
    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
                 12 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
                 13 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
                 14 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
                 15 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
                 21 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
                 22 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
                 23 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
                 24 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
                 25 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ", header=T)
table <- read.table(text="  v1  v3  v4  
    11  0.419774852 0.646429258 
                    13  0.396813214 0.922897052 
                    14  0.874210969 0.022308197 
                    15  0.997159373 0.234000934 
                    21  0.062226556 0.171017067 
                    23  0.467930927 0.273295148 
                    24  0.318980872 0.17997447  
                    25  0.323878792 0.026514599 ", header=T)
```

Variable `table$v3` is supposed to replace values in variables `df$v3_1` to `df$v3_5`. Variable `table$v4` is supposed to replace values in variables `df$v4_1` to `df$v4_5`.

The issue is that I cannot figure out how to do this in one `apply` command. As of right now, I have to use two `apply` commands:

```
cols1 <- c("v3_1", "v3_3",  "v3_4", "v3_5")
cols2 <- c("v4_1", "v4_3",  "v4_4", "v4_5")
df[,cols1] <- apply(df[,cols1], 2, function(x) table[match(df$v1, table$v1), "v3"]) 
df[,cols2] <- apply(df[,cols2], 2, function(x) table[match(df$v1, table$v1), "v4"])
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with one `apply` command? I've tried things like:

```
cols3 <- c("v3_1", "v3_3",  "v3_4", "v3_5", "v4_1", "v4_3", "v4_4", "v4_5")
df[,cols3] <- apply(df[,cols3], 2, function(x) table[match(df$v1, table$v1), c("v3", "v4")])
```

But that just creates a `v3` and `v4` variable for each `cols3` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are okay with `lapply` : (more better ways are possible though)

```
func <- function(x){
  l = grepl(x, colnames(df))   # create logical vec of which columns needs to be replaced
  df[df$v1 %in% table[[1]] ,l]=table[x] # substitute where l is TRUE
  df[l]                                 # return only the replaced column
}
cbind(df[1], lapply(colnames(table[-1]), func))
```

Comment: @joelwilson. I'm trying to get your example code to work on my actual data (i.e. not the example data above). I'm not making much process and I think the issue is that my tables are actually in a list. All the tables have the same dimensions. Also, in my actually data `df` has many more variables than just the ones that I am trying to replace values in and they happen to be in the middle of the data frame. So I am trying to use `lapply`: `New.DFs <- lapply(table.list, function(table) {cbind(df[1], lapply(colnames(table[-1]), func))})`.

Comment: It works, although not with my actual data because the columns that I am trying to replace values in are in the middle of the data frame.

Comment: add `df1 = df[!as.logical(rowSums(sapply(colnames(table), function(x) grepl(x, colnames(df)))))] ; cbind(df[1], lapply(colnames(table[-1]), func), df1)` this should keep all non-matching columns to the end

Comment: @RTrain3k o`does it answer completely your question?

Comment: @joelwilson it does. Thank you very much! I don't really understand the `df1 = ...` line but I will research on my own.

Answer (score 1):

You could do :

```
sapply(colnames(table[-1]),function(x) df[df$v1 %in% table$v1,grepl(x,colnames(df))]<<-table[,x] )
> df
   v1       v3_1       v3_3       v3_4       v3_5      v4_1      v4_3      v4_4      v4_5
1  11 0.41977485 0.41977485 0.41977485 0.41977485 0.6464293 0.6464293 0.6464293 0.6464293
2  12 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
3  13 0.39681321 0.39681321 0.39681321 0.39681321 0.9228971 0.9228971 0.9228971 0.9228971
4  14 0.87421097 0.87421097 0.87421097 0.87421097 0.0223082 0.0223082 0.0223082 0.0223082
5  15 0.99715937 0.99715937 0.99715937 0.99715937 0.2340009 0.2340009 0.2340009 0.2340009
6  21 0.06222656 0.06222656 0.06222656 0.06222656 0.1710171 0.1710171 0.1710171 0.1710171
7  22 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
8  23 0.46793093 0.46793093 0.46793093 0.46793093 0.2732951 0.2732951 0.2732951 0.2732951
9  24 0.31898087 0.31898087 0.31898087 0.31898087 0.1799745 0.1799745 0.1799745 0.1799745
10 25 0.32387879 0.32387879 0.32387879 0.32387879 0.0265146 0.0265146 0.0265146 0.0265146
```

**NB:** the use of `<<-` isn't considered as good practice as it can be dangerous.

Comment: thanks. I m trying to get your examply code to work on my actual data (i.e. not the example data above). I'm not making much process and I think the issue is that my tables are actually in a list. So I am trying to use lapply: `New.DFs <- lapply(table.list, function(table) {sapply(colnames(table[-1]),function(x) df[df$v1 %in% table$v1,grepl(x,colnames(df))]<<-table[,x] )})` Also, in my actually data df has many more variables than just the ones that I am trying to replace values in.

Comment: @RTrain3k do you mean that you have several df and table?

Comment: The variables of df that I listed in my example above are just a subset of the actual variables in the data frame. Of course, I am only interested in replacing values in the subset of variables v3_1 through v4_5. As for the table, I actually have a list of tables.

Comment: @RTrain3k that they are way more variables in the form of v3_1 v4_5 is not a problem since we are not calling them specifically, however working with a list of tables instead of one change the problem quite substantially.